# Custom NSControl of AppKit/Cocoa emulating style

Tags: macos, cocoa, appkit

I am developing a custom slider to support color selection functionality.
This is a screenshot of the current development so far:

[image]

The background coloring is very flexible and also offers to use the standard background coloring as implemented in NSSlider using system colors.

The implementation is realized by overriding a NSView rather than NSSlider, since I also want to support flexible sizes of the cells:

[image]

I am currently struggling with the shadowing of the knobs. The color sliders should be positioned right next to standard NSSliders. However, if I am not carefully replicated the shadow style of the standard NSSlider, it will look a bit awkward.

Is there any documentation on how the shadow styles (radius, offset, opacity, etc) in the standard controls are designed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To put it simply: nope.

The control styles are always subject to change, and have never ever been documented. They are what they are and it's up to you to figure it out and mimic them if you need to.